# Creating map of New Zealand with coordinates in Folium

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, folium, new-zealand

I want to create a map of New Zealand in Folium Python. I want to show the map of New Zealand. Later on I will add the markers on the map. I started coding as follow:

```py
nz_map = folium.Map(location=(lat,long), zoom_start=12)
display(nz_map)
```

I don't know exactly the coordinates of NZ. I googled the NZ coordinates and entered 40.9006 (S), 174.8860 (E). When I ran the code it shows a blank image as shown below:

[image]

I'm not sure where I made the mistake. Could anyone help me in fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2581/gene), it seems like you had longitude as a negative coordinate, this correctly shows NZ.

```
lat = -40.9006
long =  174.8860
nz_map = folium.Map(location=[lat,long], zoom_start=6)
```